# How To Set Unlimited Isolate Infinite Loop Dart Executables?

Tags: multithreading, docker, performance, dart, server

I run the exe program from dart compile but when the isolate exceeds 16 the program stops, I run it in docker how can I isolate more than 16 ?

My PC Specs

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5500u
Ram: 8GB

Btw, this is RAM usage when there is isolate 15

CONTAINER ID   NAME              CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O        PIDS
b7465b0d5526   my_app   22.12%    307.6MiB / 7.121GiB   4.22%     40.4MB / 2.37MB   46.7MB / 848MB   91

Want the program to be able to run more than 16 isolates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation you hit is the amount of simultaneous threads there are allowed to operate at the same time on the same piece of heap memory. But with a bit of work, it is possible to utilize all CPU cores on your CPU.

When using [`Isolate.spawn`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawn.html), you are spawning a new isolate that shares the same heap as the calling isolate, which makes spawning isolates really efficient since we don't need to allocate a new heap for every single isolate.

(It should be noted that Dart will still make sure only one isolate owns a piece of data in your Dart program to make sure the isolates are isolated.)

This also allows for optimizations like [`Isolate.exit`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/exit.html) where we can return data from an isolate as part of the isolate being stopped, which means we can be sure there are still only one reference to the data and can therefore send it to another isolate in the same isolate group without doing any memory copying.

There are however a catch. Because of how the garbage collector are implemented, there are a limitation on how many threads can operate on the same heap at the same time. The limitation does not prevent you to have more than 15-16 isolates in the same isolate group, but it does prevent them all from executing code at the same time (e.g. it is fine if we e.g. have asynchronously events which makes so the isolates are not 100% CPU busy).

A way to get around this limitation is spawning isolates using [`Isolate.spawnUri`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawnUri.html) which spawns a new isolate inside its own isolate group. This means this isolate will have its own heap which you can then again have 15-16 isolates inside.

Isolates made from `Isolate.spawnUri` are more resource heavy since they does allocate their own heap. It does also mean we can't use `Isolate.exit` to send data from this new isolate group to another isolate group since the two groups does not share the heap. We can, however, still send data using normal [`SendPort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/SendPort-class.html) and [`ReceivePort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/ReceivePort-class.html) which does involve copying the data in memory.

The most annoying restriction of isolates spawned from `Isolate.spawnUri` is that you are restricted in which types you can send between the isolates. You can read more about that in the documentation of [`SendPort.send()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.6/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html).

Should also be noted that `Isolate.spawnUri()` is not supported in Flutter. (see first link in "further reading")

Further reading:

- https://dart.dev/language/concurrency#performance-and-isolate-groups
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/51261
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/51254